# Pagnation with jquery and coldfusion google style

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to pagination with Google like style, I had created the pagination, if i run it it works fine, but if i use the cfdiv to load the contents and use ajaxlink to go to next record, but it is throwing an error every-time and i am checking if any jquery type solution is better

If you ask that i have not tried, i had tried and after that i am asking

here is my Code for the cfdiv

```
<cfdiv id="section_scripts" bind="url:section_scripts.cfm" bindonload="true" OnBindError="handleGError"/>
```

The above line has a file which has the code written for pagination, it displays the first only and the next one i click, it throws error

Pagination Code of the section_scripts.cfm file

```
<cfset CurrentPage=GetFileFromPath(GetTemplatePath())>
<cfparam name="PageNum_search" default="1">
<cfparam name="MaxRows_search" default="0">
<cfparam name="StartRow_search" default="0">
<cfparam name="EndRow_search" default="0">
<cfparam name="TotalPages_search" default="0">
<cfparam name="QueryString_search" default="">
<cfparam name="tempPos" default="">
<cfparam name="minimo" default="1">
<!--- setup page 1 --->
<cfset minimum = 1>
<!--- length of google bar --->
<cfset shownumbers = 5>
<!--- max rows per page --->
<cfset MaxRows_search=3>
<cfoutput>
<cfinvoke component="#application.cfcpath#.portfolio" method="getWebsites" id_external="1" returnvariable="search"/>
<!--- modify paging recordsets behavior of dreamweaver --->
<cfif search.recordcount>
   <cfset StartRow_search=Min((PageNum_search-1)*MaxRows_search+1,Max(search.RecordCount,1))>
   <cfset EndRow_search=Min(StartRow_search+MaxRows_search-1,search.RecordCount)>
   <cfset TotalPages_search=Ceiling(search.RecordCount/MaxRows_search)>
   <cfset QueryString_search=Iif(CGI.QUERY_STRING NEQ "",DE("&"&XMLFormat(CGI.QUERY_STRING)),DE(""))>
   <cfset tempPos=ListContainsNoCase(QueryString_search,"PageNum_search=","&")>
   <cfif tempPos NEQ 0>
      <cfset QueryString_search=ListDeleteAt(QueryString_search,tempPos,"&")>
   </cfif>
<cfif search.recordcount gt MaxRows_search>
   <div class="pagenum">
   <!â€”setup the numbers that we need to google bar -->
   <cfif PageNum_search gte Ceiling(shownumbers/2)>
      <cfif (shownumbers mod 2) neq 0>
         <cfset minimum = PageNum_search - int(shownumbers/2)-1>
      <cfelse>
         <cfset minimum = PageNum_search - int(shownumbers/2)>
      </cfif>
   </cfif>
   <cfif minimum eq 0>
      <cfset minimum = 1>
   </cfif>
   <!--- setup the first page or page no. 1 --->
   <cfif PageNum_search gt 1>
      <a href="#ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')#"<cfif minimum eq PageNum_search>style="font-weight:bold; color:##339966"</cfif>>First Page</a> || 
      <cfif minimum gte 2>
         ...
      </cfif>
   </cfif>

   <cfloop index="limit" from="1" to="#shownumbers#">
      <cfif TotalPages_search gte minimum >
         <a href="#ajaxlink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=#minimum##QueryString_search#')#" <cfif minimum eq PageNum_search>style="font-weight:bold; color:##FF9900"</cfif>>#minimum#</a>
      </cfif>
      <cfif minimum lt TotalPages_search>
         <cfif limit eq shownumbers>
            ...
         <cfelse>
            ,
         </cfif>
      </cfif>
      <cfif minimum gt TotalPages_search>
         <cfbreak>
      </cfif>
      <cfset minimum = minimum + 1>
   </cfloop>

   <!--- setup the last page --->
   <cfif PageNum_search lt TotalPages_search>
      || <a href="#ajaxlink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=#TotalPages_search##QueryString_search#')#" <cfif minimum eq PageNum_search>style="font-weight:bold; color:##339966"</cfif>>Last Page</a>
   </cfif>
   </div>
</cfif>

<table style="border:none;" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="roundedBox">
<cfloop query="search" startRow="#StartRow_search#" endrow="#StartRow_search + (MaxRows_search - 1)#">
   <cfif search.currentrow mod 2 eq 0>
      <cfset color ="##EEEEEE">
   <cfelse>
      <cfset color ="##FFFFFF">
   </cfif>
   <tr bgcolor="#color#">
      <td width="35%"><div class="cmsms_media_box" style="width:90% !important;margin:5px !important;padding:5px !important;border:1px dotted ##EAEAEA;">
          <figure> 
          <a title="" rel="prettyPhoto" class="preloader" href="portfolio/big_#pic#" style="background-image: none;"> <img src="portfolio/small_#pic#" alt="" class="fullwidth" style="opacity: 1;"> </a> 
          </figure>
        </div></td>
      <td width="65%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</cfloop>
</table>
</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Error I am getting

```
The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
There was an error while validation.

For more details check logs.



The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Beauty/section_scripts.cfm: line 43
41 :    <!--- setup the first page or page no. 1 --->
42 :    <cfif PageNum_search gt 1>
43 :       <a href="#ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')#"<cfif minimum eq PageNum_search>style="font-weight:bold; color:##339966"</cfif>>First Page</a> || 
44 :       <cfif minimum gte 2>
45 :          ...
```

Thanks

Comment: a) More of the code is needed so that we know what is going on b) What kind of error is being thrown? What are the details?

Comment: What is this supposed to me: "If you ask that i have not tried, i had tried and after that i am asking" ?

Comment: Any solution you use will be better than using `cfdiv`. Do yourself a favor and do not use the ColdFusion AJAX, or other client side, functionality. Learn how to do it the right way using a library like jQuery or ExtJS. You will thank me later.

Comment: @Adam, Everytime you ask me i have not tried, the code is long enough so i did not added, if that is the case, i will add the code and the exact error issue i am facing. Hope that answers your questions which is always like a memory corrupter

Comment: I can't quite make out what you mean. However by not telling us *actually* what you have tried, you are kind of expecting us to just guess, and we will end up wasting time suggesting things you might have already done. If you can't be arsed helping us to help you, you're not gonna get very far.

Comment: I have added the full info now what it is doing now, if you can suggest a better way, I would love to change it

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what is wrong.

```
The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Beauty/section_scripts.cfm: line 43
41 :    <!--- setup the first page or page no. 1 --->
42 :    <cfif PageNum_search gt 1>
43 :       <a href="#ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')#"<cfif minimum eq PageNum_search>style="font-weight:bold; color:##339966"</cfif>>First Page</a> || 
44 :       <cfif minimum gte 2>
45 :          ...
```

On line 43 you have incorrectly nested your hash tags `#`. You have this which is not allowed (You cannot have hash tags within hash tags):

```
<a href="#ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')#" ...
```

I assume you want something like this instead (I removed the hash tags that surrounded the entire ajaxLink statement):

```
<a href="ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')" ...
```

*Update after further comments*

Based on your next error I must assume that `ajaxLink` is not a file but a JavaScript function. So you need to change your `href` accordingly:

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxLink('#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#')" ...
```

Or perhaps you just want to link directly to the `section.cfm` file with the URL parameters in which case you do not need `ajaxLink()` at all.  Like this:

```
<a href="#CurrentPage#?PageNum_search=1#QueryString_search#" ...
```

I do not know what your intention is with `ajaxLink()`.

Comment: That did not worked. This is the error i got

`The web site you are accessing has experienced an unexpected error.
Please contact the website administrator. 

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
File not found: /beauty/ajaxlink(&apos;section.cfm`


URL


`http://localhost/beauty/ajaxlink('section.cfm?PageNum_search=2&_cf_containerId=sectionport&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&_cf_clientid=F6DF51EF5C9D3B62879C6B4281242022&_cf_rc=0')`

Comment: Yes it did. It fixed that problem and now you are getting another one. The code, as you have it, is attempting to create a link to a file named "ajaxLink". So my next guess is that it should actually be a JavaScript call. Right? I will update my answer...

Comment: AjaxLink creates the ColdFusion.navigate() stuff which moves between the specified div, i am amzed here why it is throwing an error

Comment: Did you change your link to reference javascript as I suggested in my updated answer?

Comment: i did , nothing helped

Comment: Ok. It's very difficult to help you without giving us specific details.

Comment: Hre is the Update, Idebugged more and found one issue in the logs folder, i am running CF10.

`CFContainerID: Invalid input. Please conform to regex ^[\p{Alnum}_\-\.:]+$ with a maximum length of 100`

Comment: That is all the Information i have, nothing more, I checked the logs of coldfusion and it showed. hostek.com has addressed this but still no valid answer: They checked for cfwindow

**http://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?651-CFWINDOW-CF-9-0-1-There-was-an-error-while-validation**